# How to turn android switch on and then off with normal animation?

Tags: android, oncheckedchanged

I would like to turn a switch on and then off. I have tried it this way:

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    swtch.setChecked(true);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(200);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    swtch.setChecked(false);
}
```

The switch will turn blue but will not move to the right. After the 200 ms it will turn gray again. It also says OFF the whole time. How can i make the switch move to ON and back to OFF again?

Comment: You could use a `handler` with `postDelayed`

Comment: Could you give an example? I tried it but my application only freezes.

Comment: Show your new code now